# Google Script Apps - Capitalize first letter of each word of input string in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, capitalize

I am looking for a solution that capitalizes each word of the input string to cell seperated by blank space or dot (similar to `proper` function). I know it is broken but what I tried so far:

```
    /*Capitalize Firt Letter of Each Word of input String in Cell*/
  if(activeRow > 1 && activeCol == 3 && ss.getSheetName() == validSheet && activeCell.isBlank() == false)
  { 
    var inputVal = activeCell.getValue().toString();
    Logger.log(inputVal);
    activeCell.setFormulaR1C1("=PROPER("+inputVal+")");
  }
```

Example:

Input for cell A2:

```
this tExt neEds to be fixed
```

Output (Desired Result) for cell A2:

```
This Text Needs To Be Fixed
```

I noticed that the proper function won't work because it requires cell value in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that takes a string and capitalizes the first letter of each word:

```
function capitalizePhrase(phrase) {
  var reg = /\b(\w)/g;
  function replace(firstLetters) {
    return firstLetters.toUpperCase();
  }
  capitalized = phrase.replace(reg, replace);
  return capitalized;
}
```

which you could then use like this:

```
var inputVal = activeCell.getValue().toString();
var outputVal = capitalizePhrase(inputVal);
activeCell.setValue(outputVal);
```

Edit - if you also want to set other letters in the word to lower case, you can use this function instead:

```
function properCase(phrase) {
  var regFirstLetter = /\b(\w)/g;
  var regOtherLetters = /\B(\w)/g;
  function capitalize(firstLetters) {
    return firstLetters.toUpperCase();
  }
  function lowercase(otherLetters) {
    return otherLetters.toLowerCase();
  }
  var capitalized = phrase.replace(regFirstLetter, capitalize);
  var proper = capitalized.replace(regOtherLetters, lowercase);

  return proper;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for initial solution. However, have few problems
1 - Only capitalizing the first word. I needed rest of them to be capitalized too
2 - When a word has a capitalized letter in it even if it not the first letter. I require it to be not capitalized

Comment: @Mimayuki I've added a full solution to my answer. The properCase function capitalizes the first letter of each word and sets the rest of the letters to lower case. Eg. properCase("the DOLPHIN is sick") returns The Dolphin Is Sick. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is perfectly working for my case. Thank you for your interest and attention. But I have one last question if you don't mind. `/\b(\w)/g` those strings are not identical for me can you explain those?

Comment: `/\b(\w)/g` and `/\B(\w)/g` are regular expressions. `/\b(\w)/g` selects the first letter of each word. `/\B(\w)/g` selects all the characters in each word except the first letter. You can read more about word boundaries (`\b` and `\B`) here https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html and see how they work here: https://regexr.com/4ara1

Answer (score 0):

I did another way, I don't know if it's better but at least, I find it simplier :

```
// Cap the first letter and minimize all the others

function CapStrings(txt) {

  var firstLetter = txt.slice(0,1).toUpperCase();
  var othersLetters = txt.slice(1).toLowerCase();

  var newTxt = firstLetter + othersLetters;

  return newTxt;

}
```